# How to write a function which accepts different object types but perform same operation in Java

Tags: java

I am using import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut and HttpGet to form the headers of my put and get requests. A lot of the headers to be added in these methods are same and I want to avoid writing the same code in both my put and get functions. Is there a way to have a function which accepts both HttpPut or HttpGet objects as parameters and will be able to add headers? For example:

```
HttpGet get= new HttpGet(url);
get = addHeaders(get);
get.setHeader();//custom headers for get requests

HttpPut put = new HttpPut(url);
put = addHeaders(put);

Object addHeaders(Object x) {
   x.setHeader();//add the common headers
   return x;
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `AbstractHttpMessage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

both `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` has implements the `HttpMessage` interface which contains a method `setHeader()` so

```
public void setHeader(HttpMessage msg){
      msg.setHeader("xxxx");
}
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Dont we need to return msg?

Comment: that return is meaningless in your example

Comment: Agreed, the *interface* HttpMessage is the proper type to use as it clearly defines the interface you need. The superclasses are implementation details.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I guess this comment is supposed to be in the other answer? :)

Comment: @AdrianShum But How will the object's value get reflect back in the calling function without returning it as Java passes by value

Comment: @user1692342 Suggest you to get better understanding of Java.  The reference (or pointer) itself is pass by value, but the copy of the pointer is still pointing at the same object instance.

Comment: @user1692342 we don't have to return msg in this case. But it just a code style. return it may hint that the method will not modify the object in place, which may cause confusion.

Answer (score 3):

`HttpMessage` is the parent of `HttpGet` and `HttpPut`.

Try this

```
HttpMessage addHeaders(HttpMessage x) {
   x.setHeader();//add the common headers
   return x;
}
```

Comment: `AbstractHttpMessage` is probably the best parent.

Comment: working against interfaces instead of class is probably even better.